# PHP doesn't like this T_String. (Syntax Error Unexpected T_STRING)

Tags: php, mysql

I was writing a MYSQL query for changing a user's password.

Part of the code is:

```
if ($newpass == $newpass2 && strlen($newpass) < 21 && strlen($newpass) > 5) {
$sqlPasswordQuery = "SELECT value FROM radcheck WHERE attribute = "Cleartext-Password" AND value = "{$oldpass}" AND username = "{$userid}"";
$oldPasswordResult = mysql_query($sqlPasswordQuery);
```

The line in the middle is the position of error (Line 56):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /(directory)/changepass.php on line 56
```

The table used stores more than one kind of properties, only when a row's attribute = "Cleartext-Password", it is the password row.

The table is generated by freeradius, and used for authorisation, so I cannot modify its structure.

I modified the code to varies kinds of styles, for example this:

```
$sqlPasswordQuery = SELECT value FROM  `radcheck` WHERE  `attribute` =  "Cleartext-Password" AND `value` = "{$oldpass}" AND `username` = "{$userid}"
```

But PHP still doesn't like it.

Could someone give a hand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Eh... it doesn't work 'cause that's not how you do strings in PHP. Read some PHP tutorials or so. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements!

Comment: "I modified the code to varies kinds of styles, for example this:" You really shouldn't try around until you find something that works in programming. Look for a manual about the language, read it. -1 for missing research effort.

Comment: Also, you should read a bit about how strings are delimited in SQL. Hint: It's not with `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the request look like that :

```
$sqlPasswordQuery = "SELECT value FROM radcheck WHERE attribute = 'Cleartext-Password' AND value = '$oldpass' AND username = '$userid'";
```

?

This is basic php string comprehension. You cannot use double quotes in a string that is already delimited by double-quotes. Sou you have to use another string delimiter, as simple quotes, or escape them (`\"`), so that they are interpreted directly as a character.

Answer (score 0):

You have two syntax errors in your code. 
First you need to use parenthesis when you use `&&` in if statemens `if((... ) && (...))`

```
if (($newpass == $newpass2) && (strlen($newpass) < 21) && (strlen($newpass) > 5))
```

Then you need to use single quote while using equal `attribute = 'Cleartext-Password'`

so your code would look like this

```
if (($newpass == $newpass2) && (strlen($newpass) < 21) && (strlen($newpass) > 5)) 
{
    $sqlPasswordQuery = "SELECT value FROM radcheck WHERE attribute = 'Cleartext-Password' AND value = '{$oldpass}' AND username = '{$userid}'";
```

Comment: You don't need inside parenthesis : `if((... ) && (...))` and `if(... && ...)` works exatly the same. That's actually overadding parenthesis for nothing.
It is necessary if and only if there are `&&` and `||` at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

String have to be quoted in PHP so you should use something like this:

```
$sqlPasswordQuery = 'SELECT value FROM  `radcheck` WHERE  `attribute` =  "Cleartext-Password" AND `value` = "' . $oldpass . '" AND `username` = "' . $userid . '"';
```

Comment: -1: Eh, double-quotes in SQL? Really?

Comment: Although you _could_ use this, be sure and check for SQL injection per @thejh's comment. Best practice would be, as he said, to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlPasswordQuery = "SELECT value FROM  `radcheck` WHERE  `attribute` =  'Cleartext-Password' AND `value` = '".$oldpass."' AND `username` = '".$userid."'"
```

Try like this.